# How do you copy a formula from a formated table to a new table with a different name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit],--(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit]<>0),Purchases_XYZ[Cost])/SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost],--(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit]<>0)),"")
```

I have 30 sheets each with the same table and needing that formula to be calculated but each table has a unique name.

So on one it might be Purchases_XYZ and on the next it might be Purchases_ABC.

How do I copy the above formula but get it to dynamically adjust based on the sheet's table name?

Comment: if all tables are already there you will have to use VBA to achieve what you want

Comment: Yep, tables are already there, so I am guessing I need to do it manually. Ug....

Comment: either manually or via VBA - that shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

This could save some time:

Formula in G5:

```
=SUBSTITUTE($E$5;$I$5;J5)
```

[image]

You also can use replace (search in formulas)

[image]

Next time before you create tables, you could switch off the Table name reference

[image]